# Clarification of a proof that the union of affine schemes is affine

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

At the end of a [proof](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01I5) on the Stacks project showing that the union of disjoint open affines is affine, we have the following statement

> By assumption the morphism $X \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(X)$ induces an isomorphism of $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_X(U))$ with $U$ and similarly for $V$. Hence $X \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(R)$ is an isomorphism.

Why is there an induced isomorphism (i.e. why is it an isomorphism, not just a morphism)? What is the induced isomorphism?

---

As an aside, the [proof](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01I5) on the Stacks project uses the fact that the $\operatorname{Spec}$ of a product is a coproduct of $\operatorname{Spec}$, so why not use a one line proof à la [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/321030)?

Comment: The argument in the linked question is perhaps more transparent. On the other hand,  it is quite aesthetically pleasing to write down a canonical morphism to an affine scheme, and then prove that it is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

The morphism $U \to \operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal O_X(U))$ is the one obtained by restricting the morphism $X \to \operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal O_X(X))$ to $U$.

That this is an isomorphism follows from the fact that $U$ is affine: suppose $U\cong \operatorname{Spec}(S)$; then, it is a standard result that $\mathcal{O}_X(U) \cong S$.